# How to push Children in Angular

Tags: angular, tree, children

I am writing a simple node tree application that takes input and I am having trouble displaying children created through input. The overall objective is to print the number of children typed into the input and all children to be in the range taken into the inputs as well. I can print a new node obviously but my logic isn't working as child of "root" and the number of children are not printing either. Please help. Any guidance would be truly helpful and appreciated. I am brand new to Angular. What am I missing?

Here's what I have:

nodetree.component.html

```
<div class="container">

    <div class= "input-div">
        <input type="text" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Enter a Name" [(ngModel)]="nodeName" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="text" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Number of Children" [(ngModel)]="nodeChildren" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="text" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Range Minimum" [(ngModel)]="nodeRangeMin" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="text" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Range Maximum" [(ngModel)]="nodeRangeMax" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 text-center">
        <ul *ngIf="nodes">
            <li class="row node" *ngFor="let node of nodes">

                <span  *ngIf="!node.editing; else editingNode" class="node-name" (dblclick)="editNode(node)">
                    > {{ node.name }}
                </span> 
                <ng-template #editingNode>
                <input type="text" class= "node-edit" [(ngModel)]="node.name" (blur)="editDone(node)" (keyup.enter)="editDone(node)" autofocus>
                </ng-template>
                <span class="node-range">
                        {{ node.rangeMin }}-{{ node.rangeMax }}
                </span>
                <div class="remove-node" (click)="deleteNode(node.name)">
                    &times;
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the nodetree.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nodetree',
  templateUrl: './nodetree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nodetree.component.scss']
})
export class NodetreeComponent implements OnInit {
  nodes: Node[];
  nodeName: string;
  nodeChildren: Node[];
  nodeRangeMin: number;
  nodeRangeMax: number;
  nodeChildNumber: number;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nodeName = '';
    this.nodeRangeMin = undefined;
    this.nodeRangeMax = undefined;
    this.nodeChildren = [];
    this.nodeChildNumber = undefined;
    this.nodes = [
      {
          name: 'Root',
          rangeMin: 12,
          rangeMax: 20,
          childNumber: undefined,
          editing: false,
          hasChildren: true,
          showChildren: true,
          children:[
            {
              name: 'Bob',
              rangeMin: 17,
              rangeMax: 30,
              childNumber: undefined,
              editing: false,
              hasChildren: true,
              showChildren: true,
              children:[]
            },
                {
                  name: '',
                  rangeMin: undefined,
                  rangeMax: undefined,
                  childNumber: undefined,
                  editing: false,
                  hasChildren: false,
                  showChildren: true,
                  children:[]
                },



        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  addNode(): void {
    // if(this.nodeName.trim().length === 0) {
    //   return;
    // }



    var nodeRangeMin = undefined,
    nodeRangeMax = undefined,
    nodeChildNumber= undefined,

    nodeName = [];

    var nodeName = [];
    while(nodeName.length < nodeChildNumber){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*(nodeRangeMax - nodeRangeMin) + nodeRangeMin);
        if(nodeName.indexOf(r) === -1) nodeName.push(r);
        return;
    }

    this.nodes.push({
      name: this.nodeName,
      rangeMin: this.nodeRangeMin,
      rangeMax: this.nodeRangeMax, 
      childNumber: this.nodeChildNumber,
      editing: false,
      hasChildren: false,
      showChildren: false,
      children:[]
      })

      this.nodeName = '';
      this.nodeRangeMin = undefined;
      this.nodeRangeMax = undefined;
      this.nodeChildNumber = undefined;
  }

  deleteNode(name: string): void {
    this.nodes = this.nodes.filter(node => node.name !== name);
  }

  editNode(node: Node): void {
    node.editing = true;
  }

  editDone(node: Node): void {
    node.editing = false;
  }

  toggleChild(node: Node) {
    node.showChildren = !node.showChildren;
  }
}

interface Node {
  name: string;
  rangeMin: number,
  rangeMax: number,
  childNumber: number,
  editing: boolean;
  hasChildren: boolean;
  showChildren: boolean;
  children: Node[];

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem here. Can you tell me what's not working on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxjdqw?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner currently it is only pushing the name and range, not the number of children entered into the input. If you enter 8 into the "number of children" input, I'd like it to print out 8 children within the range given in the "range minimum" and "range maximum." Surely I am missing some steps but again, I'm new to Angular. Further, it would be nice if the parent was collapsible as well

Comment: I see it now, a `node` can have children `nodes` which can have more children. So, what you need is somewhat recursive approach

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing

Comment: First, decide on what a `Node` is. Is it the template between `li` tags? If it has children, what should it do? Then create a component for that. Pass its config through an `Input` which may contain `children` (`Node[]`). If it has children, it should render them.

Comment: Node is the parent-yes, the template between the li tags. It should have children after the user inputs how many. I'm not sure I follow. Can you give me an example or add it to the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxjdqw?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)?

Comment: It will be easier if you update your question with a json aka your `nodes` array and expected output. It does not have to be too deep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209335/discussion-between-nick-halloway-and-bunyamin-coskuner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation, following solution is what you need.

Here is a working [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skrmmc)

Let's sum up what you are trying to do.

You will have a single `root` and create `children` with given `name` `numberOfChildren` `rangeMin` and `rangeMax`. This child will have as many children as `numberOfChildren` whose names will be decided randomly between `rangeMin` and `rangeMax`.

Let's create a `ChildComponent`

`child.component.ts`

```js
export type ChildModel = {
  name: string;
  rangeMin: number;
  rangeMax: number;
  children: number[];
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() model: ChildModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`child.component.html`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="model">
  <span>
    > {{ model.name }}
  </span> 
  <span class="node-range">
    {{ model.rangeMin }}-{{ model.rangeMax }}
  </span>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let child of model.children">
      {{child}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</ng-container>
```

And here is the

`parent.component`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `

     <div class= "input-div">
        <input type="text" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Enter a Name" [(ngModel)]="nodeName" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="number" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Number of Children" [(ngModel)]="nodeChildren" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="number" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Range Minimum" [(ngModel)]="nodeRangeMin" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
        <input type="number" class= "node-input" placeholder ="Range Maximum" [(ngModel)]="nodeRangeMax" 
        (keyup.enter)="addNode()">
    </div>

    <app-child *ngFor="let child of children" [model]="child"></app-child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  children: ChildModel[] = [];

  nodeName = '';
  nodeChildren = 0;
  nodeRangeMin = 0;
  nodeRangeMax = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addNode() {
    this.children.push({
      name: this.nodeName,
      rangeMin: this.nodeRangeMin,
      rangeMax: this.nodeRangeMax,
      children: this.generateChildren()
    });
    this.clearInputs();
  }

  private generateChildren() {
    return [...new Array(this.nodeChildren).fill(0)].map(_ => this.getRandom());
  }

  getRandom() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(this.nodeRangeMax - this.nodeRangeMin) + this.nodeRangeMin);
  }

  clearInputs() {
    this.nodeName = '';
    this.nodeChildren = 0;
    this.nodeRangeMin = 0;
    this.nodeRangeMax = 0;
  }
}
```